How do I in a batch file Move Mouse Cursor, Click Left Mouse Button?
So in this batch file, it opens a webpage after a timeout command. But on that webpage, to start the video, you need to click the video box! Which has above it an ad that doesn't work. So it can't play a video until the video box is clicked! Call it Initiating.
So, how do I mouse click in a command? So in the batch file, how can I trigger a left mouse button click? And if possible, move the mouse cursor to a pre-determined spot on the screen? Doing this, I can Click the button automatically!
Timeout is set to 00 so there is no delay. I can fudge the whole routine by having the batch file on the spot where the video is clicked, if I can get a mouse click command!
I have set the batch file:
AS SUCH
timeout 00 && start "" link is not work safe so it has been removed; however, where this line is and ends with , there is a link that opens in a browser to that page when this .bat is opened!
Comments: Works! However, if on websitee such as it is, there's an issue! To play a video, you bypass an Ad! So this PREVENTS PLAYING! DOES NOT WORK!
So, the comment stuff is mine with information removed for WS.
How can I initiate a webclick once on the website? So it takes a little while for the page to load in my browser on my computer, so maybe like a 30-second wait will guarantee it clicks the right place/time! But if I can also get a mouse cursor move command.
